# Minecraft LAN world fail

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friend and I live pretty far apart.We really want to play on a LAN world, but it won't let me see it.Can someone help please?

Comment: LAN stands for [Local Area Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network)

Comment: In other words, you have to be connected to your friend's home network to be able to play on a LAN world with them. What you will have to do is use a server if you want to play together from your houses.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set up a simple dedicated server, (which in all honesty is pretty easy), Then your best bet would be to set up a VPN. VPN stands for Virtual Private Network, and this QnA from SuperUser may be able to help you:

https://superuser.com/questions/620692/can-i-use-a-vpn-to-trick-minecraft-into-connecting-via-lan

If that doesn't work, here's how to set up a **Minecraft Server**

### Downloading and setting up the server

1. You have to download Minecraft Server jar from the Minecraft dowloads page.

[image: Webpage]

Once you download the server files from the webpage, you have to start the server from the terminal or command prompt with the highlighted command: (replace the minecraft_server.jar part with the path to your Minecraft server file eg. C:\Users\Username\Desktop\minecraft_server.version.number.jar)

[image: Command]

[image: terminal]
As you can see, when starting the server in the terminal, it says
`You need to agree to the EULA in order to run the server. Go to eula.txt for more info.`

Find the `eula.txt` file in your server's folder, and open it. change the part that says `eula = false` and set it to `eula = true`. Open the terminal, and start the server again.

Now, your server is up! It's not ready to be used yet, though. You're going to want to find the file called `server.properties` and label it `server.txt` and open it. You're going to want to change the properties to your desired settings. Now, the property you're going to want to be SURE that you change is the server IP. Set this to either the IP of your device or set it to `localhost`.

[image: Server running]

We're almost done. Now, you need to port forward your server. Do this by typing in the address of your router into your address bar in your web browser. If you don't know the IP address, you can type in `ipconfig` in command prompt, and you should see somthing that says `Gateway: 192.168.x.x` That is your router's IP address. Now, type it into the address bar, and a page similar to this should come up:

[image: Logging in to router]

Your username and password should be on a sticker located on your router. If you don't know or can't find it, ask your parents.

### Port Forwarding

[image: Port Forwarding]
Once you login, find the IP address of your device, or the name of your device, and click options for port forwarding.
You want to add an application to a new port forwarding rule for your computer. Now, if your router doesn't have Minecraft listed as an application, click custom, and in the area where it says port, change it to 25565. Click to add the rule, and you have set up your Minecraft server! Make sure you have a dedicated computer **running Pentium III or later with at least 1 GB of RAM.**